# Accessing 'background-image' css property in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, yui, background-image

I am setting the background-image of some elements using css (some elements have no background image)

```
.file-type-pdf {
    background-image: url("file-type-pdf.png");
}
```

I am then trying to determine in javascript whether certain elements have a background image or not, as follows

```
var style = YAHOO.util.Dom.getStyle(el, 'background-image');
console.log(style);
```

This works perfectly in FF, where elements with no background image return 'none' and elements with a background image return the image url.

However, in chrome and safari, the same code returns an empty string for both cases.

If i were to set a background image in the javascript code as follows, chrome and safari then return the image url 'foo.jpg' correctly

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(el, 'background-image', 'url("foo.jpg")');
var style = YAHOO.util.Dom.getStyle(el, 'background-image');
console.log(style);
```

However, I cannot work out why these browsers cannot access the background-image set through the css

Note also that this syntax (maybe more familiar to some) is producing the same results (empty string in webkit browsers but correct on FF)...

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null) || el.currentStyle;
console.log(style.backgroundImage);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If you want to be cross-browser compatible, I would suggest you check out http://nb.io/hacks/csshttprequest. It uses that property to transfer data using the data:// URI scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me on the Stack Overflow logo using the Chrome console on this page.

For vanilla JS:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("hlogo").childNodes[1];
getComputedStyle(logo).getPropertyValue('background-image');
```

For jQuery:

```
$("#hlogo a").css("backgroundImage")`
```

For YUI:

```
// You have to load YUI first.
var logo = document.getElementById("hlogo").childNodes[1];
YAHOO.util.Dom.getStyle(logo, 'background-image');
```

All return `"url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3)"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After closer inspection, the problem seems to be associated with the element node that is being passed to the particular function, as if i get the same element by id within the function, the above code works fine. - although still odd how the problem only arises in webkit browsers. I have actually come up with a better solution to my problem now than checking if the element has a bg image - so i guess this may just remain a mystery